# How to prove this ${\pi\over4}\leq\int_0^{\pi\over2}e^{-\sin^2{x}}dx\leq{11\over32}\pi$

Tags: definite-integrals, integral-inequality

Can someone help to prove this? $${\pi\over4}\leq\int_0^{\pi\over2}e^{-\sin^2{x}}dx\leq{11\over32}\pi$$

I totally have no idea how to approach.

Thanks.

Comment: A [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/489606/73025).

Comment: Sorry. I didn't get you. How is that question related?

Comment: You are asking to prove that something approximately equal to $1.01$ is between something approximately equal to $0.79$ and $1.08$. Why?

Comment: "approximately 1.01" is $\frac{\pi}{2 \sqrt{e}} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 2^{-4k}/{(k!)^2} $, for interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Taylor's expansion, we have:
$$
e^{-x^2}=1-x^2+\frac{x^4}{2}-\frac{x^6}{6}+\mathcal{O}(x^8)
$$
It means that:
$$
1-\sin(x)^2\leq e^{-x^2}\leq 1-\sin(x)^2+\frac{\sin(x)^4}{2}
$$
Integral the inequality from $0$ to $\pi/2$, we have:
$$
\frac{\pi}{4}=\int_0^{\pi/2}1-\sin(x)^2dx\leq\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{-\sin(x)^2}dx\leq\int_0^{\pi/2}1-\sin(x)^2+\frac{\sin(x)^4}{2}dx=\frac{11\pi}{32}
$$
Then your proposition is follow.

Answer (score 4):

[Integrating](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B1+-+Sin%5Bx%5D%5E2%2C+%7Bx%2C+0%2C+Pi%2F2%7D%5D) the following [inequality](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B1%20-%20Sin%5Bx%5D%5E2%20%2b%20Sin%5Bx%5D%5E4/2,%20%7Bx,%200,%20Pi/2%7D%5D) gives you that result.
$$1 - \sin^2(x) \le e^{-\sin^2(x)} \le 1  - \sin^2(x) + \frac{\sin^4(x)}{2}$$

Comment: Very nice hint! +1

Answer (score 3):

Use the fact that

$$ \exp (x) = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \ldots $$