# Prove that $2 < f(n) < 3$ if $n$ is a natural number and $n \ge 2$ and $f(n)=\left (1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Prove that $2 < f(n) < 3$ if $n$ is a natural number and $n \ge 2$ and $f(n)=\left (1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$.

I've succeded in proving that $f(n)>2$ :

$$
f(n)=\left (1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n
\\
f(n)=\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)+\binom{n}{2}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)+\binom{n}{3}\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)+...+\binom{n}{n}\left(\frac{1}{n^n}\right)
$$
Since the first two terms in this series are $1$, $f(n) > 2$. 
Can anybody give me a few hints on proving the upper bound ?
Edit : I already know of the way to do this using limits and am looking for a way to do this using the Binomial Theorem.

Comment: Use the fact that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} (1+\frac {1}{n})^n =e $$

Comment: @Rohan Thanks for the answer but I'm looking for a way to do this without limits as this is an exercise in the chapter - " Binomial Theorem " in one of my father's old math textbooks.

Comment: See my answer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489606/how-can-one-prove-that-e-pi/489638#489638 for a hint of a way to proceed

Comment: @MarkBennet This still requires us to use limits. Right ?

Comment: @VishnuV.S The method of bounding the terms individually can be used to compare with a finite geometric progression.

Comment: @MarkBennet The terms, apart from the first two are successively decreasing. But how do we prove that their sum is less than 1 ? As for a geometric progression, I can't figure out a common ratio ?

Comment: Try one half :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the AM-GM inequality, the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ given by $a_n=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ is increasing:

$$ a_n = 1\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \leq \left(\frac{1+n\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{n+1}\right)^{n+1} = a_{n+1} $$
but such sequence is also bounded above:
$$ a_n = 2+\sum_{k=2}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^k} =2+\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac{n-j}{n}\leq 2+\sum_{k\geq 2}\frac{1}{k!}$$
and it is enough to prove that $\sum_{k\geq 2}\frac{1}{k!}<1$, that simply follows from:
$$ \sum_{k \geq 2}\frac{1}{k!}<\sum_{k\geq 2}\frac{1}{k(k-1)}=\sum_{k\geq 2}\left(\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k}\right)=1.$$