# How to prove that 1/1!+1/2!+1/3!+....<3?

Tags: summation

How can I prove that 1/1!+1/2!+1/3!...<3?
Should I use mathematical induction?
I can see that the sum is the same as the power series of e^1 and that is also less than 3. But where is the proof for that?

Comment: This question boils down to proving that $e<3$. And to prove *that*, you can consult [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489606/how-can-one-prove-that-e-pi/489638#489638) thread.

Comment: You are missing a $+1$ at the beginning of the series ? ... & the exercise is probably to show $e<3$ & not assume this.

Comment: Compare it to $\frac{1}{n^2}$

Comment: The sum is actually $e-1$.

Answer (score 6):

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k!}= 1+\frac12+\frac12\sum_{k=3}^\infty\frac2{k!}\le1+\frac12+\frac12\sum_{k=3}^\infty\frac1{3^{k-2}}=1+\frac12+\frac12\cdot\frac12=\frac74$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

For some $m<n$
$$\frac1{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdots n}<\frac1{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdots m\cdot m\cdot m\cdot m}=\frac1{m!}\frac1{m^{n-m}}.$$

So starting from the $m^{th}$ term, you can bound the series by a geometric one of which you can get the value of the tail. Up to you to find a suitable $m$.